# Prove that coefficient of $λ^n$ in the characteristic polynomial is $1$.

Tags: matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

The characteristic equation is shown below

> $p\left(\lambda\right) = \det\left(A-\lambda\mathbf{I}\right) = \left|\begin{array}{cccc} a_{11}-\lambda & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}-\lambda & \cdots & a_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}-\lambda \end{array}\right|$
>
> $= \left(-1\right)^n \left[\lambda^n + c_1 \lambda^{n-1} + c_2 \lambda^{n-2} + \cdots + c_{n-1} \lambda + c_n\right]$

and it is identified the coefficient of $λ^n$ to be $(-1)^n$. but I not sure how we can prove this equal to $1$ (monic)

Comment: The coefficient is sometimes -1, it depends on whether $n$ is even or odd (specifically when $n$ is even then the coefficient of $\lambda^n$ is 1, and when $n$ is odd the coefficient is -1).

Comment: The way you show the definition of the char. polynomial, the leading coefficient is always $\;(-1)^n\;$ , not $\;1\;$ . That's the main reason why I define the char. polynomial as $\;\det(\lambda I-A)\;$, and then *yes*: we always get this way a monic polynomial.

Comment: The proof relies on your definition of determinant: which one do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Expand the determinant in minors using [Laplace's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeterminantExpansionbyMinors.html). You then see there is only one way of obtaining a term with $n$ powers of $\lambda$, namely multiplying the $n$ different $-\lambda$ together. You get
$$(-\lambda)^n=(-1)^n \lambda^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of the characteristic polynomial that you have given the coefficient will be $(-1)^n$ not $1$.
Inorder to always obtain a monic polynomial you can use the definition $$p(\lambda) = det(\lambda I-A)$$
That way the roots of the polynomials are the same (i.e. the eigenvalues can still be found correctly) but other properties will differ (e.g. it isn't necessarily monic).